# How do you pronounce Agricola?

Tags: agricola

I played my first game of Agricola yesterday.  Naturally, I'm left with a bunch of questions, but chief among them is: **How do you pronounce the name of this game?**  Our group was split pretty evenly between "AG-ri-co-la" and "a-GREEK-o-la".  Which side (or maybe neither!) is correct?

Comment: Pronounce it however you pronounce agriculture.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Erik P's [reference to Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agricola) is correct, but he is interpreting the IPA pronunciation [incorrectly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aIPA#I).
`/aˈɡri.ko.la/`  is *ah-GRIH-koh-lah*.  You can hear it pronounced by Merriam-Webster [here](http://goo.gl/5Ug8W).

Comment: +1 Thanks. I'm Dutch, so translating the latin pronunciation in my head into a fake English one is not my strong point :)

Comment: My browser crashed on that link so I looked for alternatives. I found this one for latin: http://de.forvo.com/word/agricola/ And this one for spanish: http://www.forvo.com/word/agr%C3%ADcola/

Comment: I studied Latin at Oxford, so I'd hope I'm at least a moderate authority on such matters, and this answer looks correct to me!

Comment: @Kempeth: Try [this link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agricola) and click on the little speaker symbol next to the word.

Comment: Thanks but it still crashes. The other links are enough for me...

Comment: I wasn't looking for this question, but I'm so glad I found this answer! Now to go tell my gamer friends that I was right and they should stop saying a-gri-COH-la.

Comment: Actually, Eric is right about the IPA and you are wrong. The symbol /i/ is EE, not IH, as the very Wikipedia link you gave points out.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, right, and those are the vowel in "greed", not the vowel in "grid".

Answer (score 2):

Among my group, we pronounce it "ah-greek-OH-la". Based on the fact that the designer is German, my so-so knowledge of German, and lack of facts that prove me wrong, I 'd say this is the "correct" pronounciation.

Disclaimer: I 'm Greek. We pronounce things quite differently than Americans.

Answer (score 2):

I learned ah-GREE-ko-lah in school, and Wiktionary seems to bear me out: according to [this page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agricola), the (classical) pronunciation in IPA was /aˈɡri.ko.la/, and according to [this table on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Suprasegmentals) the quote precedes the stressed syllable.

Comment: My high school Latin taught me a-GREE-ko-lah as well.  The second syllable definitely gets the stress, though as BlueRaja points out it may be "grih" instead of "gree".

Answer (score 2):

I pronounce it the way they do in Dead Poets Society (AG-ri-co-la).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxFPc3Q_Lh4&t=1m4s

Answer (score 2):

Say it however you want (don't insist that all your friends say it the 'right' way).  If you care, the author of the game pronounces it ah-GREE-ko-la.

10:20 into the interview: 
http://www.cliquenabend.de/videos/450000-Hernevideospezial-Uwe-Rosenberg.html